# How to store images in firestore collection?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am new to using firestore and was wondering how can you store images in a firestore collection. I am building an app and want to retrieve the images that are stored in the firestore collection, but i couldn't find a image datatype field. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "easy" way to store images in Firestore.  It's not designed for that.  The best you can do is encode the image as a string (for example, with base64 encoding).  Bear in mind that the maximum size of a Firestore document is 1MB, so it won't be big enough for typical photos.

I strongly suggest you look into storing images in Cloud Storage, then storing the path of the file in Firestore.  This is the most common solution.

Comment: Can you guide me as to how to store the path in the collection and how i can access it in js?